# Error in creating a function to ggplot from a dataset

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called allcountries_df with the columns country name, year, and dollars. I need to create a function that will take 3 countries as arguments and plot the dollars vs year. Here's what I have:

```
graph3countries <- function(country1, country2, country3) {
 allcountries_df %>%
      filter(`Country Name` %in% c(country1,country2,country3)) %>%
      ggplot(allcountries_df,
        aes(x=year, y=dollars, group = `Country Name`, color=`Country Name`)) +
      geom_line() +
      scale_y_log10()
}
```

When I try to call it with

```
graph3countries("France", "Spain", "Italy")
```

or

```
graph3countries(country1="France", country2="Spain", country3="Italy")
```

it returns this error:

> Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.

How do I fix this?

Edit: I don't think I pasted the code right here but I'll attach a screenshot. (Sorry, I'm very new to this!)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs8uJ.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The erros is at the `ggplot`, where we call the data again when there is a `%>%`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

graph3countries <- function(data, country1, country2, country3) {
data %>%
 filter(`Country Name` %in% c(country1,country2,country3)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=year, y=dollars, group = `Country Name`, color=`Country Name`)) +
   geom_line() +
   scale_y_log10()
}
```

call it as

```
graph3countries(allcountries_df, "France", "Spain", "Italy")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
allcountries_df <- structure(list(`Country Name` = c("France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy"), year = c(1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 
1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L), dollars = c(5506L, 5012L, 
7368L, 9505L, 5711L, 6667L, 6596L, 9541L, 7324L, 6123L, 6458L, 
9611L, 5096L, 8309L, 7252L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I added in the data argument but it's still giving me the same error message. graph3countries <- function(data, country1, country2, country3) {
  allcountries_df %>%
  filter(`Country Name` %in% c(country1,country2,country3)) %>%
  ggplot(allcountries_df,aes(x=year, y=dollars, group = `Country Name`, color=`Country Name`)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_log10()

Comment: Same as the last one,  Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.

Comment: @0427092 if the column names are correct, then it shouldn't be an error

Comment: @0427092 now, you are changing the function with `data` as formatl parameter and inside you are calling  `allcountries_df` two times which is not my function.  Please use the function as I showed

Comment: Ok I tried that, now it says Error in graph3countries(allcountries_df, "France", "Spain", "Italy") : 
  unused argument ("Italy")

Comment: @0427092 are you using the same function or different one.  I am guessing that you are using old function which have only 3 parameters as input

Comment: I did exactly what you said in the first reply

Comment: @0427092 Maybe you copy/pasted the first function and that may be the reason

Comment: @0427092 I updated with the data and graph got